# Connect Android phone via mtp

Tags: android, kde-plasma, manjaro, mtp, gvfs

System: manjaro.
Desktop profile: kde.

I tried to connect an Android phone via mtp, but it failed. The error message is as follows:

```sh
$ mtpfs
Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=12d1 and PID=107e) is a Huawei P9 Plus.
   Found 1 device(s):
   Huawei: P9 Plus (12d1:107e) @ bus 1, dev 14
Attempting to connect device
libusb_claim_interface() reports device is busy, likely in use by GVFS or KDE MTP device handling alreadyLIBMTP PANIC: Unable to initialize device
Unable to open raw device 0
```

It shows that my device is busy and may be occupied by GVFS or KDE MTP. I tried to kill them, but it didn't work.

I have the following questions:

1. I cannot see any device mount points under the /run/user/1000/gvfs folder. This is an empty folder. How to deal with this?
2. How to solve the problem of GVFS or KDE MTP occupying my device?
3. How can I directly use GVFS or KDE MTP to access my device? The operation of the command line environment is required, and the operation of the GUI environment is not required.

Answer (score 0):

apt-get install mtp-tools

it worked for me

Comment: Did not work for me: same as @aszswaz (Kubuntu 22.04)